# Mixing libstdc++ versions

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

There are 2 software teams developing C++ applications for the same OS (Scientific Linux 6.5):

**Team_A** uses the OS provided compiler and libraries (GCC 4.4.7, GLIBC_2.12, GLIBCXX_3.4.13), to build its C++98 application and various shared libraries.

**Team_B** uses a newer GCC version (4.8.3) which has been built from source. It's a native compiler, it links against the OS libc, and uses the OS standard headers, but has its own version of stdc++ (GLIBCXX_3.4.19). Team_B uses this compiler in C++11 mode to build its application (**AppB**), and deploys libstdc++ and libgcc_s along with it.

Team_A provides services to Team_B in form of a shared library (.so, .hpp): **LibA**. The API of the library is a set of C++ classes (declaration in the header, implementation in the .so), and the methods take std::string and other stdc++ classes as arguments.

At this point we arrive to the problem: AppB constructs GLIBCXX_3.4.19 C++11 style std::whatever objects and passes them to LibA who interprets them as GLIBCXX_3.4.13 C++98 style objects, and this might not be forward compatible.

Is this a problem? Can it lead to an application crash? Are the std::whatever implementations compatible among versions (same memory layout)? What about c++98 vs C++11?

Some plot twists which make me more confused:

- AFAICT, when AppB runs there's only one libstdc++ loaded, the newer
  one. Even if LibA links against the older, it won't be loaded.
- But symbols in libstdc++ are versioned. So, if LibA explicitly uses an
  older version of a symbol it will be linked against that. This means
  2 different implementations of the same function will be used by AppB
  and LibA.
- std::string and containters are template classes, this means
  part of their implementation end up where it's generated, part of it
  in libstdc++.so. Even if the newer libstdc++ is loaded, the generated
  template code in LibA is from the older version.

I would like to understand what's exactly happens in this case, if it is risky, and void problems. Getting the teams on the same development environment is not an option. Removing std:: classes from the API would also be very hard to make.

Any pointers welcome! :)

Comment: This is exactly why people suggest you don't use C++ types in a public, dynamic interface. GLIBCXX might have some mechanism to deal with this gracefully (I don't know), but in general this can easily lead to crashes and other forms of undefined behavior. Mixing different standard library implementations is a good way to break the [one definition rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule).

Comment: Some incompatibilities between library and language versions are [listed here](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Cxx11AbiCompatibility), but it only covers GCC versions up to 4.7.

Comment: To see how binary compatibility is managed for libstdc++, see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html. C++98 vs C++11 is a compil time problem : once produced, binaries are just elf (with mangled symbol names for c++).

Comment: If it is possible in your context you could just recompile TeamA's source code with TeamB's compiler, stdlib and compiler settings to produce SOs which can be used by TeamB's code without any problem?

Comment: @kispaljr: this is a good option, but TeamA provides SO's primarily because they don't want to release their source, and complicated build procedures.

Comment: I built two modules with a common interface that uses std::string. one with -std=c++11 and the other with -std=c++98. I linked them with the same version of g++ with no -std option. For both g++ 5 and g++ 4.9 with libstdc++ 6.0.21, I had no issues. This was only a very basic test. But I would like to understand how to reproduce the compatibility issues that everybody gets so excited about but which nobody can talk about. Are we all spending a lot of money worrying about something that is easy to avoid hitting?

Comment: Interestingly, with g++ 5, there is a new namespace std::__cxx11 which was used by default for both c++98 and c++11 compiles

Comment: @codeshot Yes, I also bumped into this recently, it clarifies incompatibilities (linker error). But g++ 5 has dual ABI, and it can generate code that is ABI compatible with g++ 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike C, there is no defined ABI for C++.  That means ....

1. The C++ mangling may change [wikipedia : name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#How_different_compilers_mangle_the_same_functions).  Note how Alpha name mangling changed.
2. The structure of a class may be different.  There may be different decisions for laying out `protected:`, `private:` and `public:` parts of the structure.  The location and meaning of the vtable may be moved between compilers.  There may be different pre-defined functions such as the typeinfo in the vtable between the different compiler versions.
3. The implementation of a structure in the STL may be different between versions of C++ (e.g. string sharing was done in earlier Visual studio implementations, but has been banned in C++11).
4. In Windows, different runtimes may manage their memory differently (bind to different malloc/free).  When passing full objects or pointers, this can result in the incorrect free implementation being called.

What can you do to mitigate these problems?

### Source sharing

Instead of providing a compiled library, deliver the services as source code to be compiled on the same environment.

### Standardize on libstdc++

The source built compiler, can be re-built with the older stdC++.  This would limit the impact of point 3).

### Create a facade

There is an interface between the two teams, which needs to speak a common language.  This language probably ought to be C.

Team A => C++ facade/stub =>  C interface => C++ facade/proxy => Team B.

The facade should be built in the environment where it will be used.